# Hive joining on between condition

Tags: hive, hql, hiveql

I am having trouble with joining 2 tables based on 'between' condition in Hive. Basically because Hive doesn't support these joins I don't know how to work around it. Basically, I want to join two tables based on date column where t1.date<=t2.date and t1.date>=t2.tdate2. No other columns match in the tables. How can i achieve that?h

Comment: for that you need one common key from both the table then and then you can join this table and after that apply this condition.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion first apply filtering and modify on one of the table and then apply join.

```
select t.id, new.id from (select t1.id from temp t1, new_temp t2 where t1.id > t2.id)t join new_temp new on (t.id = new.id);
```

This should work. I have tested with test cases that came to my mind.

Following are other approaches you may think of but wont work.

**1. Apply where with join**

```
select t1.id, t2.id from temp t1 join new_temp t2 on (t1.id = t2.id) where t1.id < t2.id
```

=> this query will execute join first and then condition so there will no row in output.
You can check execution flow by executing :

```
 explain select t1.id, t2.id from temp t1 join new_temp t2 on (t1.id = t2.id) where t1.id < t2.id;
```

**2. Apply where after join**

```
select * from (select t1.id as t1id, t2.id as t2id from temp t1 join new_temp t2 on (t1.id = t2.id))new_table where t1id < t2id;
```

Here as join is already applied, every time t1id and t2id will be equal.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question. I am giving a work-around, so it might help somebody.
I agree, the BETWEEN,< and > operators work within JOIN clauses in Impala. But do not work in Hive as of now.

I have a work-around for it. I know it is not an efficient way, but it works. It is based on the logic, explode the elements between the (date) range and use to join both tables.

```
WITH
date_range AS (
  SELECT 'dt1' AS date_code, '2020-01-01' AS start_dt, '2020-01-31' AS end_dt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'dt2' AS date_code, '2020-02-01' AS start_dt, '2020-02-29' AS end_dt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'dt3' AS date_code, '2020-03-01' AS start_dt, '2020-03-31' AS end_dt
)
,dates_breakup AS (
  SELECT distinct date_code, date_add(rd.start_dt, dts.days) as active_dt
   FROM date_range rd LATERAL VIEW posexplode(split(space(datediff(rd.end_dt,rd.start_dt)),' ')) dts as days, x
),my_data AS (
 SELECT '2020-01-15' AS txn_dt
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '2020-02-10' AS txn_dt
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '2020-05-12' AS txn_dt
)
SELECT a.txn_dt, b.date_code
 FROM my_data a
  LEFT JOIN dates_breakup b ON b.active_dt=a.txn_dt
;
```

Output:

```
+-------------+--------------+--+
|  a.txn_dt   | b.date_code  |
+-------------+--------------+--+
| 2020-01-15  | dt1          |
| 2020-02-10  | dt2          |
| 2020-05-12  | NULL         |
+-------------+--------------+--+
```